# Bind two JSF input fields with single property of backing bean

Tags: jsf-2

Suppose I have two `h:inputText` components. I want to bind both of the text fields with single property in the backing bean. The problem is that the value submitted to backing bean is that from second text field. I want that the value should be submitted from that field in which user entered the text.

My code:

```
<h:inputText id="text1" value="#{bean.value}">
    ......
</h:inputText>


<h:inputText id="text2" value="#{bean.value}">
    .......
</h:inputText>
```

**Note** that the value in both of the above fiekds is `bean.value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `<f:ajax event="blur"...` or `<f:ajax event="keyup"...`

like this

```
<h:inputText id="text1" value="#{inningBean.dismissalName}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="typeWhatYouWant" listener="#{optionalBean.someMethod}"/>
</h:inputText>


<h:inputText id="text2" value="#{inningBean.dismissalName}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="typeWhatYouWant" listener="#{optionalBean.someMethod}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

or using js (check your `text1` and `text2` real ids using viewsource)

```
<h:inputText id="text1" value="#{inningBean.dismissalName}" onkeyup="$('#yourFormID\\:text2').val($('#yourFormID\\:text1').value)"/>



<h:inputText id="text2" value="#{inningBean.dismissalName}" onkeyup="$('#yourFormID\\:text1').val($('#yourFormID\\:text2').value)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have reached this freaking situation just for avoiding server requests where these are not necessary, this is certainly not a choice for me.

Comment: now this is a good idea, can you please include it in your answer, so that I can accept your answer