# Use jQuery to sync values of Primefaces JSF2 components (inputText)

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

i want to use jQuery to sync values of JSF2 components. 
We are using templates. As i am not sure if this may be a cause why the below script is not working, i will show you the code design:

**template.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="main_form">
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**myview.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition ... template="templates.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
    <p:inputText id="title1" value="#{myBean.title1}" />    
    <p:inputText id="title2" value="#{myBean.title2}" />
    <p:commandLink id="syncBtn" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e" />
</ui:define>
```

**my.js**

```
$('#main_form\\:syncBtn').click(function() {
    $('#title2').val($('#title1').val());
});
```

The jQuery scripts/functions are not attached to the elements

I know i can use callbacks (onblur, onclick, etc), but i want to avoid this because and use a more generic solution because i have a lot of those input fields.

**EDIT**:
i tried BalusC answer (which is of course correct), but there must be another error. because it did not work. I inserted an js alert, but it´s not being dispayed.

```
$('[id="main_form:syncBtn"]').click(function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

Comment: you can keep em sync all in "real time" with onkeyup , like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10981475/617373

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But i want to give the user more control and let him decide to copy the values from one field to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because they don't have a client ID of `title1` and `title2`, so jQuery can't find them. They have instead an ID of `main_form:title1` and `main_form:title2`. Fix your JS code accordingly.

```
$('#main_form\\:syncBtn').click(function() {
    $('#main_form\\:title2').val($('#main_form\\:title1').val());
});
```

For starters who haven't memorized how exactly JSF generates HTML, you should ignore the JSF source code when writing jQuery code and instead look at the JSF-generated HTML code. You can do that in the webbrowser by rightclick and *View Source* or using the "Inspect Element" feature of the webbrowser's web developer toolset.

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)